# Why is my jQuery UI Spinner not incrementing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dom

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong.  I am trying to create a spinner to keep track of a bid in a game of Pinochle...
The spinner should have a minimum of 50 to start and should increment by 1's until the bid reaches 60, then the spinner should increment by 5's until the bid reaches 100, from there the bid should increment by 10's. (no max has been determined yet... so I am not worried about that)

here is the code I have tried unsuccessfully:

```
$('#bid').spinner({
            min: 50,
            spin: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.value > 60) {
                    $(this).spinner({                               
                        step: 5
                    });
                    return false;
                } else if (ui.value > 100) {
                    $(this).spinner({
                        step: 10
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

The spinner works up until it reaches 60, then it wont increment... but decrements and increments by 5's, between 50 and 60???

Can someone please show me the correct way to do this, Thank you!

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2z76bvg1/)

Comment: `$('#bid').spinner({
 min: 50,
 spin: function (event, ui) {
  if (ui.value >= 60 && ui.value<100) {
   $(this).spinner({                               
    step: 5
   });
  }
  if (ui.value >= 100) {
   $(this).spinner({
    step: 10
   });
  }
 }
});`

Comment: @Alive to Die nope still nothing

Comment: can you create a fiddle example link so that we can check. (or any other example link with your code and dummy data). You can check answers given below too

Comment: I've actually never done that, so give me a second... but I will

Comment: @AlivetoDie there you go... again any help is appreciated

Comment: you need to add you jquery and spinner library too. nothing is happening there

Comment: I have it referenced externally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using on spin event:

```
$("#spinner").spinner({
  min: 50,
});
$("#spinner").on("spin", function(event, ui) {
  if (ui.value > 60) {
    $(this).spinner("option", "step", 5);
  }
  if (ui.value > 100) {
    $(this).spinner("option", "step", 10);

  }
});
```

demo:http://jsfiddle.net/dxmcj1na/

Comment: this was my first thought too, but it still gets hung up at 60